# Подключение jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Только начинаю юзать библиотеку jQuery. Столкнулся с ошибкой, коткорую не понимаю как исправить. Вот код файла script.js:

```
//Функция возвращает рандомное число в заданном промежутке
function randomcolor(min_random, max_random)
{
    var t = max_random - min_random +1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*t) + min_random;
}

//меняет цвет
function change_color(color)
{
    elembody = document.body;
    elembody.fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
    elembody.bgColor = color;
    elembody.fadeTo(1500, 1);
}

//Точка входа
window.onload = function()
{
    colors = ["#00FFFF", "#000000", "#0000FF", "#808080"];
    setInterval("change_color(colors[randomcolor(1,4) - 1])", 4000);
}
```

Вот код файла html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Changer</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Abra-kadabra
</body>
</html>
```

Пишет ошибку:

> elembody.fadeTo is not a function
>
> [Прерывать на этой ошибке]
> elembody.fadeTo(2500, 0,3);

Прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: используй разметку, Люк.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, попробуйте заменить `elembody = document.body;` на `elembody = $(document.body);`

---

UPD #1. Чтобы изменялся фон страницы замените `elembody.bgColor = color;` на 
`elembody.css({backgroundColor: color});`

Comment: исправил, появилась другая ошибка: f.easing[e.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function. Помогите разобраться

Comment: А какая версия jQuery у вас? и в каком файле возникает ошибка? я так понимаю в приведенном вами коде этой строчки нет. И оформите код в вопросе соответствующим образом. И что у вас за браузер. У меня в хромиуме 12 Ubuntu все работает без ошибок.

Comment: v1.6.2. В файле jquery.js это и есть сама библиотека jquery

Comment: У меня такая же версия jquery - все работает, вы точно весь ваш код выложили?

Comment: хм.. странно. Выложите свой содержимое файла html и самого скрипта js пожалуйста

Comment: HTML - http://pastebin.com/vYMXBNUm
script.js - http://pastebin.com/1Q2sthLK

Comment: и что меняет плавно цвета?
А должен менять фон всей страницы причём разными цветами)